# AngularJS - Intermodule services

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I have this problem whenever I try to access a service I have declared at the very top of my main app in other modules... this is how I declare my services...

```
var myapps = angular.module('myapps',['customDirectives','imgGall','starApp', 'NavBarModel', 'Carousel', 'angular-carousel', 'eXcomments','confirmButton','Status']);

myapps.factory('RateService', function() {
    var ratings = '1';

    return {          
        getRatings : function() {
            return ratings;
        },
        setRatings : function(rate) {
            ratings = rate ;
        }
  };
});
```

and this is how I access to the service that I have created...

```
var starApp = angular.module('starApp', []);
starApp.controller('StarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http, RateService, breadcrumbsService ) {
$scope.rating = 1;
$scope.ratings = [{
    current: 1,
    max: 5
}];


$scope.getSelectedRating = function (rating) {
    RateService.setRatings(rating);
    console.log(rating);
}
}]);

--Some--More--Codes--
```

and I am keep getting such errors saying that my setRating is undefined?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRatings' of undefined
at k.$scope.getSelectedRating (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/ng.js:242:17)
at http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:176:387
at k.N.(anonymous function) [as onRatingSelected] (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:53:175)
at k.scope.toggle (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/ng.js:275:23)
at http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:176:387
at http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular-touch.min.js:11:401
at k.$eval (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:15)
at k.$apply (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:293)
at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular-touch.min.js:11:383)
at HTMLLIElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost/viralenz/assets/4483d5da/jquery.js:3058:9) angular.js:10046
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should have

```
['$scope', '$http', 'RateService', 'breadcrumbsService' , function ($scope, $http, RateService, breadcrumbsService )
```

You have to properly "inline annotate".

Comment: Owh wow thank you so much my friend!!!! I did not know annotations does effect...

Answer (score 0):

First - you forgot to declare a module dependency:

```
angular.module('starApp', ['myapps']);
```

Second - you have to repeat your dependencies as strings in the array:

```
starApp.controller('StarCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'RateService', 'breadcrumbsService', function ($scope, $http, RateService, breadcrumbsService ) {
```